# Doubt hindering my intution about vector bundles

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, self-learning

Lee, Introduction to smooth manifolds, defines a vector bundle $\pi :E \rightarrow M$ via some local trivialization maps $\pi^{-1}(U) \rightarrow U \times R^k$, where $U \subset M$.

There is something about this that is a bit hindering my intuition. Do I have to consider $R^k$ here as some coordinates of a vector space, or as a fixed vector space itself? Why did not Lee define just a fixed a vector space $V$ and define trivializations as functions $\pi^{-1}(U) \rightarrow U \times V$?.

A vector space $V$ is still a manifold and in some sense this definition is less confusing for me because $R^k$ can be either considered as a fixed vector space, or some coordinates after fixing a base in $V$... $U \times R^k$ looks to me a bit weird since $U$ is just a subset of a manifold, whereas $R^k$ looks like some coordinates in a chart.

Please be patient and consider that I am still trying to build a basic understanding/intuition..

Comment: I prefer doing it with a given vector space $V$. And on a similar note, even in the definition of a manifold, rather than restricting myself to having to map into an open subset of some $\Bbb{R}^n$, I like having the definition with charts simply being maps into an open subset of some (finite-dimensional) normed vector space (of a fixed dimension of course), because this allows us to think of the identity map as being a chart. But it doesn’t really matter because afterwards, the vector bundle transition maps have to be fiberwise linear, so $\Bbb{R^k}$ must be considered a vector space.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a reference where a vector space is introduced in the definitions? (if yes, you can also add it to the answer of Alice in Wonderland...)

Comment: For such presentation, see Loomis and Sternberg (they only do manifolds, not vector bundles in general), Lang, Abraham Marsden (eg their classical mechanics book or the tensor analysis book with Ratiu as co-author as well), and Dieudonne (Vol III, section 16.15 is about vector bundles).

Comment: Thanks. What is the book of Lang you are referring to?

Comment: He has two books, I think they’re called *Fundamentals of Differential Geometry*, and *Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds*. One of these models everything with Banach spaces, while the other restricts to finite-dimensions (though in fact for much of the basic definitions, it doesn’t really matter).

Comment: grear thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I studied vector bundles, the definition my professore gave was with a generic vector space $V$. 
I think Lee decided to go with $\mathbb{R}^k$ in order to emphasize the fact that it is a real vector space **of dimension $k$**.

Comment: Given also the good feedback you have from the community I will accept this answer, if other contributions do not come soon... Do you have a reference where such a presentation of vector bundles is being performed?